# Significance of four-velocity components in general relativity

Tags: general-relativity, metric-tensor, coordinate-systems, vectors, velocity

Suppose I consider a stationary, axially symmetric spacetime geometry characterized by the metric:
$$ds^2=g_{\mu\nu}dx^\mu dx^\nu=g_{tt}dt^2+2g_{t\phi}dtd\phi+g_{\phi\phi}d\phi^2+g_{rr}dr^2+g_{\theta\theta}d\theta^2$$

It is obvious that the metric coefficients $g_{\mu\nu}$ are independent of $t$ and $\phi$ due time translation invariance and axial symmetry and so they are functions of $r$ and $\theta$, i.e., $g_{\mu\nu}=g_{\mu\nu}(r,\theta)$. In particular, I am using the [Kerr geometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerr_metric) for studying motion around spinning black holes. Now, I am having doubts regarding the significance of the four-velocity components $u^\mu=(u^t,u^r,u^\theta,u^\phi)$ for a observer moving in the geometry.

In Newtonian gravity, we could use the superposition of velocities to study the motion of particles, e.g., a velocity vector has components along all the three axes and we can study the motion along each direction. I don't think the same is valid in general relativity. So, I am interested to know the significance of the four-velocity components in this context.

Comment: What do you mean by the superposition not being valid in GR?

Comment: @newtothis I meant that we cannot apply the same laws of vector algebra in GR as in Newtonian case.